# What is the best way to define a class from C code with SWIG?

Tags: c, swig

It's pretty common in C to see the following pattern:

```
/* struct definition */
typedef struct {int x,y,z} vector_t; 

/* Methods that always take defined struct as first argument */
int vector_add_scalar(vector_t *v, int s);
int vector_sub_scalar(vector_t *v, int s);
```

Obviously in OOP the analogue is to have a vector object and then the above functions become its methods. What I'd like to know is the best way to use SWIG to translate the above example to its OOP equivalent. Should I define a class from scratch in my interface file (in which case I might as well write my own bindings)? Are there command line options that I'm missing? Or maybe the `%extend` directive is what I'm looking for, despite the fact that all examples I've seen involve writing your own code in the interface file? Any and all input would be appreciated!

Comment: Here is some information: http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#SWIG_nn31 . Briefly: you can map `vector_t` to own class.